# iOS Grids, Panels for a XAML \ AXML developer.

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-autolayout

I am trying to layout the screen below. It is a relatively simple layout that I could easily do Android's axml or Windows' XAML. However in iOS I do not know where to start.

[image: Desired screen layout]

iOS lacks a StackPanel, LinearLayout and static Grid equivalent. It has tables but they need to be either dynamic or as far as I know a single static table per screen.

The area highlighted in Red would be a simple two column Grid in XAML, how should I do that in iOS?

The area highlighted in Green that encompasses the area in Red would be a StackPanel in XAML or a LinearLayout in Android. Again how would I do that in iOS?

FWIW I am developing using Xamarin but this question is not Xamarin specific

Comment: Have you tried Xamarin.Forms? It allows you to create the UI with Xaml which you seem to be used to.

Comment: X.F is great but... in my opinion although excellent for simple apps and perfect for prototypes... Xamarin.Forms is not ready for producing complex UIs for production apps yet (or wasn't last time I checked - to be fair a while ago).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a few months old, but in case it helps - check out MarkupKit:

https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit

It's an open-source project I created specifically to address this type of use case. It allows you to build native iOS user interfaces using markup similar to XAML or Android. Based on the mockup above, I'd suggest using an instance of LMTableView for the root view and cells containing a combination of LMRowView and LMColumnView. If you are targeting iOS 9 and above, you could also use UIStackView.

You can find an introduction to MarkupKit's major features here:

https://gkbrown.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/introducing-markupkit/

Comment: @MemeDeveloper I don't know, but I would love to find out. Does Xamarin support any kind of Objective-C interop? If so, there's a good chance it would work. Two things I'd be curious to learn are: a) if properties declared in C# are KVC-compliant and b) how C# methods map to Objective-C selectors. This would have an impact on outlets and actions are mapped to to controller class members.

Comment: @MemeDeveloper It looks like [KVC is supported](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/databinding/), so at least outlets should work. Even if actions aren't supported, you could still wire up your event handlers yourself using outlets.

Comment: thanks for that great, we will try and give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I prototyped this using MarkupKit. You can see the results below:

[image]

The markup I used to generate the view is as follows:

```
<LMTableView style="groupedTableView">
    <!-- User name -->
    <?sectionHeaderView?>
    <LMRowView layoutMarginTop="6" layoutMarginBottom="6" layoutMarginLeft="12" layoutMarginRight="12" backgroundColor="#0085e1">
        <UILabel text="BOB ADAMS" font="System 13" textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LMRowView>

    <?sectionBreak?>

    <!-- Next appointment detail -->
    <?sectionHeaderView?>
    <LMRowView layoutMarginTop="6" layoutMarginBottom="6" layoutMarginLeft="12" layoutMarginRight="12" >
        <UILabel text="NEXT APPOINTMENT" font="System 13" textColor="#808080"/>
    </LMRowView>

    <UITableViewCell textLabel.text="11:30 - in 1 hour 55 minutes" textLabel.textColor="#ffffff" textLabel.font="System 13" backgroundColor="#2e5785"/>

    <LMTableViewCell>
        <LMColumnView>
            <LMRowView>
                <UILabel weight="1" text="MCLEAN, Jim" font="System-Bold 18"/>
                <UILabel text="36y" font="System-Bold 18"/>
            </LMRowView>

            <LMColumnView alignToGrid="true">
                <LMRowView>
                    <UILabel text="Born" font="System 13" textColor="#808080"/>
                    <UILabel text="27-Feb-1978"/>
                </LMRowView>

                <LMRowView>
                    <UILabel text="Gender" font="System 13" textColor="#808080"/>
                    <UILabel text="Male"/>
                </LMRowView>

                <LMRowView>
                    <UILabel text="NHS Number" font="System 13" textColor="#808080"/>
                    <UILabel text="111 222 3333"/>
                </LMRowView>

                <LMRowView>
                    <UILabel text="Postcode" font="System 13" textColor="#808080"/>
                    <UILabel text="Z99 9ZZ"/>
                </LMRowView>
            </LMColumnView>
        </LMColumnView>
    </LMTableViewCell>

    <?sectionBreak?>

    <!-- Daily summary -->
    <LMTableViewCell accessoryType="disclosureIndicator">
        <LMRowView>
            <UILabel weight="1" text="Appointments Today"/>
            <UILabel text="3" textColor="#808080"/>
        </LMRowView>
    </LMTableViewCell>

    <LMTableViewCell accessoryType="disclosureIndicator">
        <LMRowView>
            <UILabel weight="1" text="Downloaded"/>
            <UIActivityIndicatorView activityIndicatorViewStyle="gray" animating="true"/>
            <UILabel text="4" textColor="#808080"/>
        </LMRowView>
    </LMTableViewCell>

    <LMTableViewCell accessoryType="disclosureIndicator">
        <LMRowView>
            <UILabel weight="1" text="Appointments Progress"/>
            <UILabel text="1" textColor="#808080"/>
        </LMRowView>
    </LMTableViewCell>
</LMTableView>
```

I didn't include any images because I didn't have access to the assets you used in your mockup. However, they would be easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how sophisticated you want to get.

The simplest setup is to create a UIView that is your container, then you manually add all the views that you have for labels and text.   You would have to do the sizing yourself.

If you use auto-layout, you would still need to create all eight views, but you could specify the rules for how the views would be attached and linked together.

Auto layout comes in handy when you consider that the UI will be used with other form factors where you could add rules for how it should expand.

You can design the cell on the designer and reference the various slots from your code to fill them in as well.